linux bash -> sed (regex). How to replace all appeared defined sections with "source_dir" and "target_dir" to content which in source_dir section
For example I have this text:
<<<<<<<<< <<source_dir>>
tesst
<<<<<<<<< <<target_dir>>
tes23442141
<<<<<<<<<
good
safasf

<<<<<<<<< <<source_dir>>
tesst241241
<<<<<<<<< <<target_dir>>
tes23442141
<<<<<<<<<

safasfas

And section is
<<<<<<<<< <<source_dir>>
[any text -> first text]
<<<<<<<<< <<target_dir>>
[any text -> second text]
<<<<<<<<<

And I want replace all this section to only first text
For example output must be:
tesst
good
safasf

tesst241241

safasfas

I have this sed :
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s#<<<<<<<<< <<source_dir>>\n\(.*\)\n<<<<<<<<< <<target_dir>>.*<<<<<<<<<#\1#g' "$target_file"   

But as output I have:
tesst
<<<<<<<<< <<target_dir>>
tes23442141
<<<<<<<<<
good
safasf

<<<<<<<<< <<source_dir>>
tesst241241

safasfas

And question how I can fix it?)
I understand the problem but I don't understand how to do it>
Please help me!

So does it have to be sed? Does it have to be posix?

@KamilCuk it must be sed

Neither of these is in any way Linux-specific, removed the according tag.

sed is not the best choice of tool for anything spanning multiple lines. Why does it have to be sed? Also, you didn't answer @KamilCuk's other question - does it have to be posix (since you tagged the question with [tag:posix])?

@Ed Morton
Yes it can be posix too. I just need the best solution.

"it can be posix" != "it has to be posix". Sounds like you're saying it doesn't have to be posix. And, again, why does it have to be sed given sed isn't the best choice of even just the mandatory POSIX tools for this?

@EdMorton yeah you are right. I just need the best solution. If better posix -> OK

The simplest solution would be to exclude the character < from regex:
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s#<<<<<<<<< <<source_dir>>\n\([^<]*\)\n<<<<<<<<< <<target_dir>>[^<]*<<<<<<<<<#\1#g' "$target_file"

Output:
tesst
good
safasf

tesst241241

safasfas

Please note, that if text contains character <, this would no work.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed '/^<\+ <<source_dir>>/d;/^<\+ <<target_dir>>/{:a;N;/^<\+$/M!ba;d}' file

Delete a line beginning <<<<<<<<< <<source_dir>>.
Delete any lines between a line beginning <<<<<<<<< <<target_dir>> and <<<<<<<<<.

I know you said you wanted a sed solution but sed isn't the best choice for any problem involving multiple lines. The following, for example, will work using any awk (including POSIX) in any shell on every Unix box and IMO couldn't be much simpler/clearer:
$ awk '/^</{type=$2; next} type != "<<target_dir>>"' file
tesst
good
safasf

tesst241241

safasfas

That just says:

/^</{type=$2; next} - If the current line starts with < then save the string at the end of it, i.e. <<source_dir>> or <<target_dir>> or nothing, in a variable named type then don't do anything else with this line of input. So this sets type and ensures we will not print any line starting with <.
type != "<<target_dir>>" - If while reading the current line (which does not start with < as the above statement would handle that) the variable type (which was set when the last line that started with < was read) is set to <<target_dir>> then skip it, otherwise print it. So this tests type to ensure we will not print any lines between the <... <<target_dir>> line and the subsequent < line.

If your other text can have lines starting with < then just tweak that /^</ regexp to be whatever it needs to be to identify your target <<<... lines.
